# How to fix Google Earth Engine ee.Image.getDownloadURL inconsistent output array dimensions

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api, array, dimensions

`ee.Image.getDownloadURL(..., {'dimensions': '100x100', ...})` occasionally returns arrays with shape `(101, 100)` or `(101, 100)` or `(101, 101)` instead of the expected `(100,100)`. I can't explain it since the `dimensions` parameter should control the *cropping dimensions to use for any band* according to the [Google Earth Engine documentation](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-getdownloadurl).

Please find some code here below to reproduce the issue, very much inspired by [Noel Gorelick's excellent blogpost on batch downloads from GEE using the python API](https://gorelick.medium.com/fast-er-downloads-a2abd512aa26).

**Notes**

- Occasionally means I am running this on >100K coordinates and this happens for about one percent. I haven't found any pattern yet in the data.
- For the few plots I inspected, the additional row or column was always all zero's. I could filter these out as a post-processing, but this is really not my preferred option since other mosaics than the Sentinel-2 used here as example will contain zero's as data.
- Playing with `maxError` for the `.buffer()` and `.bounds()` methods didn't help so far.

```py
# Imports
import numpy as np
import ee
import requests
import io
import geemap

# Initialize GEE Python API
ee.Initialize(opt_url="https://earthengine-highvolume.googleapis.com")

# Define geometries from coordinates
aoi_0 = ee.Geometry.Point((-8.12587073, 40.42675599)).buffer(500).bounds()
aoi_1 = ee.Geometry.Point((15.59197903, 77.53979159)).buffer(500).bounds()
aoi_2 = ee.Geometry.Point((24.00901427, 70.31953934)).buffer(500).bounds()
aoi_3 = ee.Geometry.Point((16.78013361, 77.64157263)).buffer(500).bounds()

# Generate Sentinel-2 (greenest) composite
def add_S2_NDVI(img):
    ndvi = img.normalizedDifference(["B8", "B4"]).rename("NDVI")
    return img.addBands(ndvi)

image = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED').filterDate('2018-01-01', '2018-12-31').map(add_S2_NDVI).qualityMosaic("NDVI")

# Core function using .getDownloadURL()
def get_data(aoi, image):
    """Handle the HTTP requests to download an image."""
    # Generate the desired image from the given point.
    img = image.clip(aoi).select('B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B8')

    # Fetch the URL from which to download the image (data).
    url = img.getDownloadURL({"region": aoi, "dimensions": "100x100", "format": "NPY"})
    
    # Handle downloading the actual pixels.
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    if r.status_code != 200:
        r.raise_for_status()

    arr = np.array(np.load(io.BytesIO(r.content)).tolist())
    return arr

arr0 = get_data(aoi_0, image)
arr0.shape # (100, 100, 4), this is the expected behavior

arr1 = get_data(aoi_1, image)
arr1.shape # (101, 100, 4) # unexpected
np.all(arr1[0,:,:] == 0) # True

arr2 = get_data(aoi_2, image)
arr2.shape # (101, 100, 4) # unexpected
np.all(arr2[-1,:,:] == 0) # True

arr3 = get_data(aoi_3, image)
arr3.shape # (101, 100, 4) unexpected 
np.all(arr3[0,:,:] == 0) # True
```